# Is there any algorithm that can be applied to this program?

Tags: python, algorithm, comparison

I am doing an intern writing a program to do gene matching.

For example:
File "A" contains some strings of gene type. (the original data is not sorted)
rs17760268
rs10439884
rs4911642
rs157640
rs1958589
rs10886159
rs424232
....

and file "B" contains 900 thousands of rs number like above (also not sorted)

My program now can get correct results, but I would like to make it more efficient.

Is there any algorithm that can be applied to this program?

BTW, I will try to make my program do multi-processing and see if it gets better performance.

```
pseudocode:
read File "A" by string, append to A[]
A[] = rs numbers from File "A"

read File "B" by string
for gene_B in file_B_reader:
    for gene_A in A:
        if gene_A == gene_B:
            #append to result[]
```

Comment: what exactly do you append to result? the gene that was common in both files?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without any reproducible examples we can't do much for you.

Comment: [reading-and-writing-files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and  [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) or [frozensets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) should help you make your pseudocode into a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a need to sort anything first.

- Process larger list B into a hashmap or hashset, O(n) amortized
- Iterate over list A and remove from A if not in B, O(m)
- return A

Total: O(n + m)

Comment: And if neither list fits in memory?

Comment: Good question.  The OP would need to solve a slightly different problem.  Assuming  2-byte character encoding, and 11 chars for each "gene", then I think the space required for storage is 2 * 11 * 1e6(bumped up to 1 million genes) = 2.2e7B or 22MB.  I think it's safe to assume most devices will have enough memory available.  If OP has restrictions then they should mention that in their request.

Comment: Would dictionary be better than hashmap in this case?

Comment: I believe dictionary is the generic term. Hashmap/set is generally an implementation. Python [dictionaries, maps, hashmap,...](https://dbader.org/blog/python-dictionaries-maps-and-hashtables) all seem to refer to a similar structure.

Answer (score 0):

From the description it appears you want `result[]` to contain `rs` strings that are in both `A` and `B` (aka [Intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection)).

Your algorithm is `O(n*m)`, but you could easily improve this by sorting both files first (`O(n*logn)` for comparison based sorts), and then read from both at the same time, increasing position in one that has lower current `rs` number, and adding matches to `result[]` at the same time.

Comment: You probably mean O(nm) ?

Answer (score 0):

Though your explanations are quite unclear, I guess that you are appending the A values to a list. Use a dictionary instead, and you can lookup A much more efficiently.